# CoreMotion - get left-right, bottom-up movement on iPhone in landscape

Tags: ios, swift, accelerometer, core-motion

I am making an App which able to make panorama video in landscape. In landscape, it supports two directions: left to right and bottom to top.

So I want to move an arrow from left to right when user move the phone from left to right or rotate to right. Also want to move the arrow bottom to top when move the device vertically upwards.
In native iPhone camera app with panorama option, there we can see the correct simulation,

My questions are 1) how do I know user is moving the phone from left to right or right to left. Because like iPhone panorama, I want to stop recording when user move back.

Also 2) how do I know user is moving the phone vertically upwards

---

Added : Nov 10, 2017:
I did see an app named Spincle in AppStore. It is moving the arrow when rotate the device from left to right to take 360 image. I just managed to achieve this using pitch and roll (see the below code). But this will not work if we stand device to floor or roof a bit.

```
import UIKit
import CoreMotion
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private let motionManager = CMMotionManager()
    let arrowView = UIView()
    func startMotion() {
        var initialAttitude: CMAttitude?
        motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1
        let queue = OperationQueue.current!
        let statusBarOrientation = UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation
        motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdates(using: CMAttitudeReferenceFrame.xArbitraryZVertical, to: queue) { (motiondata, err) in
            guard let data = motiondata else { return }
            if initialAttitude == nil {
                initialAttitude = data.attitude
            } else {
                let attitude = data.attitude
                // translate the attitude
                attitude.multiply(byInverseOf: initialAttitude!)
                // calculate pitch and roll of the change from our initial attitude
                let pitch = self.radiansToDegrees(attitude.pitch)
                let roll = self.radiansToDegrees(attitude.roll)
                print("\nroll = \(roll), pitch = \(pitch), yaw = \(self.radiansToDegrees(attitude.yaw))")
                print("x = \(data.userAcceleration.x), y = \(data.userAcceleration.y), z = \(data.userAcceleration.z)")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    var rect = self.arrowView.frame
                    var addXPixel = self.view.frame.size.width/45
                    var addYPixel = self.view.frame.size.height/45
                    if statusBarOrientation == .landscapeRight {
                        addXPixel *= -1
                    } else {
                        addYPixel *= -1
                    }
                    rect.origin.x = (CGFloat(pitch) * addXPixel)
                    rect.origin.y = (self.view.frame.size.height/2 - 20) + (CGFloat(roll) * addYPixel)
                    self.arrowView.frame = rect
                }
            }
        }
    }
    func stopMotion() {
        motionManager.stopDeviceMotionUpdates()
    }
    func radiansToDegrees(_ radian: Double) -> Float {
        return Float(radian * 180.0/Double.pi)
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(arrowView)
        arrowView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }
    @IBAction func tappedButton() {
        arrowView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.size.height/2 - 20, width: 40, height: 40)
        startMotion()
    }
}
```

The issue is it will go left to right a bit and the arrow moving upwards or downwards

Comment: Did you get the solution ? actually I am working on same thing I want to create image something like panorama and move arrow accordingly. Please help me if you can.

Comment: yes, we can get the angle of rotation while device rotating

Comment: Can you please share some code or description to implement it ?

Comment: I was bit busy, sorry. posted below. mark it if it helped to find the solution.

Comment: @jpulikkottil Can you share, please, how this would need to be edited for portrait. I'm struggling to see what changes are needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CLLocationManager` to check the heading of your phone, and write your algorithm to determine the left-right / bottom-top movement by calculating `CLHeading`'s degrees.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager 
        didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading*)newHeading
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clheading

Comment: let me check. But the Spincle app works even if location data is turned off.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the application on Landscape mode, so this answer is based on that. Maybe a little bit changes needed make it work for Portrait.

We will get the device X, Y and Z rotations by using the following code. Here We stored the initial value to get the difference of angle from the start position.

```
var initialAttitude: CMAttitude?
    var initialRoll: Float?
    var initialRotation: Float?//+20171219
    func startMotion() {
        initialAttitude = nil
        initialRoll = nil
        initialRotation = nil
        //leaving first two values to confirm we are starting from corect
        var counter = 0
        motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.001//+20180206
        let queue = OperationQueue.current!
        //
        motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdates(using: CMAttitudeReferenceFrame.xArbitraryZVertical, to: queue) { [weak self] (motiondata, _) in
            guard let strongSelf = self, let data = motiondata else { return }
            if strongSelf.initialAttitude == nil || counter < 2 {
                strongSelf.initialAttitude = data.attitude
                //initialize roll for horixontal rail
                let myRoll = data.attitude.roll.toDegree()
                strongSelf.initialRoll = abs(myRoll)
                //initialize yaw for vertical rail
                let rotation = (atan2(data.gravity.x, data.gravity.y) - Double.pi).toDegree()
                strongSelf.initialRotation = abs(rotation)
                //printDebug("myRoll = \(myRoll), myYaw = \(myYaw)")
                globalMainQueue.async {
                    strongSelf.delegate?.updatedMotion(roll: 0, pitch: 0, yaw: 0)
                }
                counter += 1
            } else {
                let attitude = data.attitude
                let myRoll = attitude.roll.toDegree()
                let rotation = (atan2(data.gravity.x, data.gravity.y) - Double.pi).toDegree()
                // translate the attitude
                attitude.multiply(byInverseOf: strongSelf.initialAttitude!)
                // calculate pitch and roll of the change from our initial attitude
                let quat = attitude.quaternion
                let pitch = (atan2(2*(quat.x*quat.w + quat.y*quat.z), 1 - 2*quat.x*quat.x - 2*quat.z*quat.z)).toDegree()
                //printDebug("x = \(data.userAcceleration.x), y = \(data.userAcceleration.y), z = \(data.userAcceleration.z)")
                let absRoll = abs(myRoll)
                var newAbsRoll = abs(absRoll - strongSelf.initialRoll!)
                if absRoll < strongSelf.initialRoll! {
                    newAbsRoll *= -1
                }
                printDebug("rotation = \(rotation)")
                let absRotation = abs(rotation)
                var newAbsRotation = abs(absRotation - strongSelf.initialRotation!)
                if absRotation > strongSelf.initialRotation! {
                    newAbsRotation *= -1
                }
                //printDebug("newAbsRoll = \(newAbsRoll), pitch = \(pitch), newAbsRotation = \(newAbsRotation)")
                globalMainQueue.async {
                    strongSelf.delegate?.updatedMotion(roll: newAbsRoll, pitch: pitch, yaw: newAbsRotation)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Feel free to ask if need any clarification.

Comment: Can you please share some demo code so i can get better idea?